# how to get title of of row selected in UITableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have tableview with some names on each cell , how can i get that name when select row  ?

i know that i have to use delegate method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but how can i get that title of that row ?

thanks in advance

regards

Comment: Rows don't have titles.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: i mean each cell in UItableview

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
}
```

This snippet retrieves the selected cell and stores its `text` property in a `NSString`.

---

However, **I do not recommend this**. It is better to keep the data and presentation layers separate. Use a backing data store (e.g. an array) and access it using the data in the passed `indexPath` object (e.g. the index to use to access the array). This data store will be the same one used to populate the table.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you're using a standard UITableViewCell, you can get the cell by using

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

then access the text property view properties via:

```
cell.textLabel.text
cell.detailTextLabel.text
```

Comment: (+1) Usefull to me even the small typo mistake. in the code it is UITableViewCell and you write UITableView (but you write it correctly in the text above.

Comment: Thanks a lot... You saved my day... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Once you've registered one of your classes as a delegate via the [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) delegate property you simply implement the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, which would be called when the user selected a row. (See the [UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.)

You could then extract the label text from the selected cell via...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *cellLabelText = cell.textLabel.text;
    }
```

..if this is really what you require.

Answer (score 2):

you can access each row of your uitabelview using the following (uitableview-)function:

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]
```

by the way, to access your tableview in other methods than uitableview's delegate method, you have to hook it up in IB (for example..)

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *rowTitle=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;   
}
```

Here,

[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] gives you the selected cell and then the .textLabel.text gives you the label for that cell.