# assign the selected cell label title to a property

Tags: iphone, ios

**Update :**

I have a `tableview` with some static cells in it. I want to get the `textLabel` of "Selected Cell" and want to assign it to a `NSString` property.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you Explain what you want Exactly ?

Comment: I want to assign the title text of the selected static cell to a property

Comment: I found exactly what I was looking for finally

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444312/how-to-get-title-of-of-row-selected-in-uitableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer :**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   //Now you can use cell.textLabel.text to get the title text of the selected static cell and assign it to your Property.
   NSString *yourStr = cell.textLabel.text;
}
```

Comment: yepp I just discovered this. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to examine value of each indexPath. Try something like:

```
cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"World %d", indexPath.row];
```

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for the titles are different words not just a number change.

Answer (score 0):

1) define a NSArray property,

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *titlesArray;
```

2) add the titles to the array,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.titlesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Title 1",@"Title 2",@"Title 3",@"Title 4",@"Title 5",@"Title 6",@"Title 7", nil];
}
```

3) Use them like this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.titlesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Now I have blank cells when the table is loaded.

Comment: do you set the delegate and datasource of the table view to self?